# OpenOffice Calc - 11 Pages in spreadsheet, but print interface only shows 2

Tags: printing, openoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I am working on a spreadsheet using OpenOffice and need the pages to be printable.

You can print the first two, but thats it. If in the print interface I select all sheets it only shows 1 and 2 with no options for any more.

Any help on this?

In short, I have 11 pages in the spreadsheet but can only print the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to define print ranges. I just selected the cells on each page and then went:

format->print ranges->add